# Windows: Enable/Disable Lock Screen Password With Shortcut

Tags: windows-10, security, desktop, power-management

On Windows 10, personal machine, at home, I'm looking for a way to create a shortcut, that uses a PS script or external program, that I can use to quickly change the behavior of the machine when the display turns off.

I've the machine set to turn off the display after 5 minutes of inactivity and it requires a password when I move the mouse or tap any key. Is there a way to create a desktop shortcut that will disable this password prompt / go straight into the desktop and another to enable it again?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this machine meeting corporate requirements, e.g, in use at work, or at home by VPN to office? If so, change that login requirement at you own peril -- IMHO, it ain't worth losing a job. If it's your own, just change the timeout and/or grace period: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/47389-change-screen-saver-password-grace-period-windows.html

Comment: Personal machine at home, no AD or any other requirement. I just want an easy way / shortcut to disable the password prompt when I wake the screen because I don't need the extra security when I don't have strangers at my place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make two .reg files for the key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` to export the DWORD value `ScreenSaverGracePeriod` in two different states -- your normal grace period, in seconds (e.g., 60) and a far longer one, e.g., 3600. Create two keyboard shortcuts to the .reg files. Disadvantages:

   - An extra click is needed in UAC to allow changes to the Registry.
   - On some machines, very long grace periods are not honored.
2. You can also do this with a PowerShell script, below, from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578414/setting-windows-screensaver-require-password-with-powershell)

   ```
   Function Set-OnResumeDisplayLogon {
     Param ([Int32]$value)
     [Int32]$nullVar = 0
     $systemParamInfo::SystemParametersInfo(119, $value, [REF]$nullVar, 2) }
   ```

   Call it by **Set-OnResumeDisplayLogon(*x*)**, where *x*=*0* to stop password requirement, and *1* to enable it. Again, UAC may be a nuisance.

Comment: Well I followed the PowerShell suggestion if it works if I call the script from an admin PowerShell prompt, however if I call it from a shortcut, even if set to `run as admin` it wont change the value. My shortcut is `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe C:\Users\XXX\SleepLock.ps1` any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind, aparently doing `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -f "C:\Users\XXX\SleepLock.ps1"` - note the `-f` and quotes around the script path fixed the situation, seems to work even without elevation.